# get faster results, reduce load time php

Tags: php, optimization

I have written this function:

```
public function returnAllFeeds($responseType = RESPONSE_RETURN)
{

    $twitter = $this->getTwitterFeeds();
    $instagram = $this->getInstagramFeeds();
    $facebook = $this->getFacebookResponse();

    $allFeeds = $this->sortNjoin($twitter,$instagram, $facebook);

    if($responseType == RESPONSE_JSON)
    {
        echo json_encode($allFeeds);
    }
    else
    {
        return $allFeeds;
    }
}
```

where all the feeds from twitter, facebook and instagram is fetched but everytime php gets data it takes atleast 5-6 seconds, so i wanna know if their is a way to reduce curl fetching time.

here's more code:

```
public function getFacebookResponse($responseType = RESPONSE_RETURN)
{
    $params = array(
        'access_token' => FACEBOOK_TOKEN,
        'limit' => '30',
        'fields' => 'message,permalink_url,id,from,name,picture,source,updated_time'
    );
    $fbFeeds[] = $this->curl_library->getFacebookPosts('godoolallyandheri',$params);
    $fbFeeds[] = $this->curl_library->getFacebookPosts('godoolallybandra',$params);
    $fbFeeds[] = $this->curl_library->getFacebookPosts('godoolally',$params);
    if($responseType == RESPONSE_JSON)
    {
        echo json_encode($fbFeeds);
    }
    else
    {
        return array_merge($fbFeeds[0]['data'],$fbFeeds[1]['data'],$fbFeeds[2]['data']);
    }
}
public function getTwitterFeeds($responseType = RESPONSE_RETURN)
{
    $twitterFeeds = '';
    $this->twitter->tmhOAuth->reconfigure();
    $parmas = array(
        'count' => '61',
        'exclude_replies' => 'true',
        'screen_name' => 'godoolally'
    );
    $responseCode = $this->twitter->tmhOAuth->request('GET','https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json',$parmas);
    if($responseCode == 200)
    {
        $twitterFeeds = $this->twitter->tmhOAuth->response['response'];
    }
    $twitterFeeds = json_decode($twitterFeeds,true);
    if($responseType == RESPONSE_JSON)
    {
        echo json_encode($twitterFeeds);
    }
    else
    {
        return $twitterFeeds;
    }
}

public function getInstagramFeeds($responseType = RESPONSE_RETURN)
{

    $instaFeeds = $this->curl_library->getInstagramPosts();

    if(!myIsMultiArray($instaFeeds))
    {
        $instaFeeds = null;
    }
    else
    {
        $instaFeeds = $instaFeeds['posts']['items'];
    }
    if($responseType == RESPONSE_JSON)
    {
        echo json_encode($instaFeeds);
    }
    else
    {
        return $instaFeeds;
    }
}
```

not really concern with sortNJoin it takes only ms to perform

Comment: Welcome to the world of network latency

Comment: Thanks so can i expect any answer related to this?

Comment: We have no way of answering this without seeing what all of those functions do (`getTwitterFeeds()`, `getInstagramFeeds()`,`getFacebookResponse()`, `sortNjoin()`).  I ASSUME you're using curl in these function, since you mention it in your question, but if you don't show it, you can't expect an answer

Comment: here added the code